# Copy project from Windows 10 to MacOS Catalina and open using Visual Studio Code - Ionic & Angular

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, windows-10, project, macos-catalina

I created an Ionic project using VSCode in Windows 10. I now want to deploy the app using XCode in MacOS. I copied the folder that contains the project over to MacOS, but I'm unable to open a "Folder" in MacOS VSCode as I'm able in Windows.

How do I go about migrating + opening my project in MacOS VSCode?

**Research:** I tried to drag the folder onto the VSCode icon in the dock, but it gives me an error saying it is a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie mistake:
Downloaded Visual Studio instead of Visual Studio Code.